# Plotting currents data on a map : Too many value to unpack error

Tags: python, matplotlib

So here is my code :

```
from netCDF4 import *
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nc=Dataset('datasets/essai.nc')

time_var = nc.variables[str('forecast_time0')]
wave_var = nc.variables['DIST_GDS0_SFC']
lat = nc.variables['g0_lat_1'][:]
lon = nc.variables['g0_lon_2'][:]
uin = nc.variables['UOGRD_GDS0_DBSL'][:]
vin = nc.variables['VOGRD_GDS0_DBSL'][:]
plt.quiver(lon[::5], lat[::5], uin[::5], vin[::5], scale=200)
```

And here is the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nctry.py", line 37, in <module>
    plt.quiver(lon[::5], lat[::5], uin[::5], vin[::5], scale=200)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2877, in quive
r
    ret = ax.quiver(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 6627, in quiver
    q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\quiver.py", line 394, in __init
__
    X, Y, U, V, C = _parse_args(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\quiver.py", line 356, in _parse
_args
    nr, nc = U.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I think the problem comes from the UOGRD and VOGRD which has many values but don't know how manipulate it?

Here is how my uogrd looks like :

http://www.imgjoe.com/x/microsofprp.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, welcome to the site. That said, I think this question might have been better off on the standard StackExchange site as it is more about plotting the data rather than GIS per say. Still, happy to help :)

Looking at the documentation for the [quiver plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver) we get the following:

- All arguments may be 1D or 2D
- If X and Y are 1D and U and V are 2D and the length of X and Y is the same as the length of the rows and columns of U an V then they will be expanded as a meshgrid. If not there will be an error
- You don't actually need the X and Y arrays if you just want a quick look at the data

With the slicing you're doing currently you're getting every 5<sup>th</sup> value in each array in the first dimension. Assuming that lat and lon are single dimension arrays then you're getting every 5<sup>th</sup> lat and lon value. As UOGRD and VOGRD are two dimensional arrays you're getting every 5<sup>th</sup> *column*, which means that you won't have enough rows from your latitude and longitude to expand out.

Couple of things to do:

- Plot the Quiver without the latitude and longitude to see what your UOGRD and VOGRD look like (I suspect it will be a rectangle):

```py
plt.quiver(uin[::5], vin[::5], scale=200)
```

- Take a look at the size of all your arrays and make sure that you have enough values for rows and columns.

```py
print lon[::5].shape, lat[::5].shape, uin[::5].shape, vin[::5].shape
```

- If you want to plot only every 5<sup>th</sup> value, slice the UOGRD and VOGRD arrays in both dimensions for the plot.

```py
plt.quiver(lon[::5], lat[::5], uin[::5, ::5], vin[::5, ::5], scale=200)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was not able to understand completly the documentation